# How would I get all values of a Powershell Object added to a collection from a Foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have this function that takes the InterfaceIndex from $interfaceIPs and obtains the matching NetRoute data, and puts all of that together in a collection. Currently on the terminal I have 3 separate active IPv4 addresses, but when I print the collection, I only get one, matched with the data from its respective NetRoutes.

```
function Get-InterfaceRoutes {
    $collection = @()
    $interfaceIPs = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object -Property IPv4Address, InterfaceIndex

    Foreach ($interfaceIP in $interfaceIPs) {
        $route = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex ($interfaceIP.InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -Property ifINdex, DestinationPrefix, NextHop, RouteMetric, ifMetric
        $collection = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Index = ($interfaceIp.InterfaceIndex)
            Address = ($interfaceIP.IPv4Address)
            DestinationPrefix = ($route.DestinationPrefix)
            NextHop = ($route.NextHop)
        }
    }

    Write-Host  "Collection of items: " ($collection | Format-List | Out-String)
}
```

And this is the output:

> Collection of items:
>
> Index             : 16
> Address           : {169.254.71.100}
> DestinationPrefix : {255.255.255.255/32, 224.0.0.0/4, ff00::/8, fe80::b0b4:b9b0:df22:4764/128...}
> NextHop           : {0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, ::, ::...}

I want to have the collection show all of the active IP addresses, which should be 3, matched by the Index to its corresponding NetRoute data.

If I am way off base and there is a MUCH easier way to do this, please feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The helpful comments from [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) already explained the basic problem, the re-assignment to the variable `$collection`.

In PowerShell though, most of the time you don't need to **explicitly** create and add to arrays because PowerShell automatically creates an array when you capture output of a function or a statement into a variable. This is also much more **efficient** because PowerShell has to **recreate** an array every time you use `+=` (arrays are actually of **fixed size**!). When PowerShell automatically creates an array from captured output, it uses a [more efficient data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) under the hood.

So I would modify the function like this:

```sh
function Get-InterfaceRoutes {
    $interfaceIPs = Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select-Object -Property IPv4Address, InterfaceIndex

    Foreach ($interfaceIP in $interfaceIPs) {
        $route = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex ($interfaceIP.InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -Property ifINdex, DestinationPrefix, NextHop, RouteMetric, ifMetric

        # Implicit output!
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Index = ($interfaceIp.InterfaceIndex)
            Address = ($interfaceIP.IPv4Address)
            DestinationPrefix = ($route.DestinationPrefix)
            NextHop = ($route.NextHop)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have removed the `$collection` variable alltogether!

Instead, the `[PSCustomObject]@{}` is *implicit* output of the function. PowerShell writes it to the *success stream*, from where it can be captured by the caller or simply let it pass through to display it in the console.

Now when you actually want to *collect* the output of that function into an array variable, you simply **assign** it to the variable.

```sh
$routesArray = @(Get-InterfaceRoutes)

"Collection of items:" 
$routesArray | Format-List
```

The `@()` [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) makes sure that you always create an array, even if the function outputs only a single object.

---

That being said, there are cases where you actually want to collect **intermediate** output in an array variable. Say you wanted to store the output from the `foreach` in a local variable for further processing. In this case you still don't need to explicitly create an array, just assign from the `foreach` statement to a variable:

```sh
# [array] is an alternative to @() for ensuring an array
[array] $collection = Foreach ($interfaceIP in $interfaceIPs) {
    $route = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex ($interfaceIP.InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -Property ifINdex, DestinationPrefix, NextHop, RouteMetric, ifMetric

    # Implicit output, will be captured and added to $collection
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Index = ($interfaceIp.InterfaceIndex)
        Address = ($interfaceIP.IPv4Address)
        DestinationPrefix = ($route.DestinationPrefix)
        NextHop = ($route.NextHop)
    }
}
```

---

Finally, if you really really want to explicitly create an array (e. g. when you need to add to two arrays from one loop), I recommend to use the [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) class, which is more efficient than a raw array for repeated additions. In addition it supports all operations of a raw array, e. g. you can use the index operator `[]` to access its elements.

```
# Create an instance of List, with elements of type Object.
$collection = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new() 

Foreach ($interfaceIP in $interfaceIPs) {
    $route = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex ($interfaceIP.InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -Property ifINdex, DestinationPrefix, NextHop, RouteMetric, ifMetric

    # Add a custom object to the list
    $collection.Add( [PSCustomObject]@{
        Index = ($interfaceIp.InterfaceIndex)
        Address = ($interfaceIP.IPv4Address)
        DestinationPrefix = ($route.DestinationPrefix)
        NextHop = ($route.NextHop)
    })
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the help zett! I will definitely be implementing this into my code, as encountering a few other minor annoyances can be worked around with this.

Comment: @NickKeele Glad to be helpful! :)